# How can I fix unmet dependencies - react?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I am trying to reinstall an old project from react but am getting weird errors that I don't understand. I tried to change the version of react to newer but didn't work. I am currently using npm 8.11.0 and node v16.15.1 Using the command "npm log" I got this message. But I don't know how to fix the unmet dependencies if someone can help.
[image]

**UPDATE:**
After downloading the yarn the new error is like this:
But I don't know what i have to do with the link
[image]

Comment: have you try `npm install` first?

Comment: @AsaduzzamanAtik yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### delete node_modules

install yarn package manager
and run `yarn`. It should update all depenedencies to latest version. then `yarn start` for running react-application

Answer (score 0):

npm `>= 7` has some breaking changes and it tries to install `peerDependencies` automatically.

Try to run `npm install` with npm version `6.x.x` or if you want to do it with npm version `>= 7` then use a flag `--legacy-peer-deps` like

```bash
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```